# Assigning in Swift a value but it thinks its nil

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I am following the Stanford iOS Swift development course and have to make my displayValue an optional double, I assign a value to displayValue func performOperation but the getter for var displayValue: Double? reads it as nil, I have even hardcoded var displayValue: Double? to be 81 (example) but it is still read as nil, has anyone got any ideas? (I didn't want to post my whole code but if I've missed something out let me know!), thanks!

EDIT: here is my whole code now!

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var isThereApoint = true
var openStack = Array<Double?>()
var count = 0

@IBOutlet weak var history: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var calcView: UILabel!

var historyStack = Array<String>()
var userIsTyping = false

@IBAction func numberButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let numberButton = sender.currentTitle!
    if calcView.text!.rangeOfString("=") != nil{
        calcView.text! = ""
    }

    if userIsTyping{
        calcView.text! = calcView.text! + numberButton
    }
    else {
        calcView.text! = numberButton
        userIsTyping = true
    }

}

@IBAction func decimalPoint(sender: AnyObject) {
    if isThereApoint == true {
    calcView.text! = calcView.text! + "."
        isThereApoint = false
    }
}

var displayValue: Double? {
    get{
        if NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(calcView.text!) != nil{
            return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(calcView.text!)!.doubleValue

        }
        else {
            println("calc view in getter: \(calcView.text!)")
            return 0
        }
    }
    set{
        calcView.text! = "\(newValue)"
        userIsTyping = false
    }

}

@IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton) {
    let operation = sender.currentTitle!
    switch operation{
    case "×":   performOperation ("×, ", {$0 * $1})
    case "÷":   performOperation ("÷, ",{$1 / $0})
    case "+":   performOperation ("+, ", {$0 + $1})
    case "−":   performOperation ("−, ", {$1 - $0})
    case "√":   performOperation ("√, ", {sqrt($0)})
    case "Cos": performOperation ("Cos, ", {cos($0)})
    case "Sin": performOperation("Sin, ", {sin($0)})
    case "PI":  displayValue! = M_PI
                enter()
    default: break
    }
}

func performOperation(operatorSymbol: String, operation: (Double, Double) -> Double) {
    if openStack.count >= 2 {
        println("\(operatorSymbol)")
        displayValue = operation(openStack.removeLast()!, openStack.removeLast()!)
        println("display value : \(displayValue!)")
        var displayAnswer = displayValue!
        history.text! = history.text! + operatorSymbol
        calcView.text! = "= \(displayAnswer)"
        enter()
        //calcView.text! = "= \(displayAnswer)"
        }
    }

@IBAction func positiveOrNegative(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (calcView.text!.rangeOfString("-") != nil) {
        calcView.text! = dropFirst(calcView.text!)
    }
    else {
        calcView.text! = "-\(calcView.text!)"
    }
}

func performOperation(operatorSymbol: String, operation: Double -> Double) {
    if openStack.count >= 1 {
        displayValue = operation(openStack.removeLast()!)
        var displayAnswer = displayValue!
        history.text! = history.text! + operatorSymbol
        enter()
        calcView.text! = "= \(displayAnswer)"
    }
}

@IBAction func clearButton() {
    history.text! = ""
    for item in openStack{
        openStack.removeLast()
    }
    calcView.text! = ""
}

@IBAction func backspace(sender: AnyObject) {
    if countElements(calcView.text!) > 0 {
        calcView.text! = dropLast(calcView.text!)
    }      
}

@IBAction func enter() {
    isThereApoint = true
    if history.text! == "History"{
        history.text! = ""
    }
        openStack.append(displayValue!)
        var userIsTyping = false
        println("openStack  = \(openStack)")
        history.text! = history.text! + "\(displayValue!)" + ", "
        calcView.text! = ""
}
}
```

Comment: where is your assignment in your code?

Comment: displayValue = operation(openStack.removeLast(), openStack.removeLast()) but it keeps returning nil!

Comment: Does openStack contain ints or doubles?

Comment: What do you get if you print out the value of `NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(calcView.text!)!.doubleValue` before you return it in the getter?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Did you see my question? What are you inputting into openStack upon entry?

Comment: Well there you go that's your problem. Print out `calcView.text` what is that? Something like 2 x 3 + 5?

Comment: Oh sorry openStack is an array of doubles! need to make it an array of optional doubles then? and calcView.text is Optional(20.0) for 4, 5, x (so 4 * 5)

Comment: changed the array to double? but the getter still returns 0!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are setting `calcView.text` to `"Optional(81.0)"`.  You need to unwrap the `Double?` that is in `newValue` inside of `set` for `displayValue`:

```
set {
    calcView.text = "\(newValue!)"
    userIsTyping = false
}
```

Because the displayValue was `"Optional(81.0)"`, `NSNumberFormatter` couldn't convert the value, so it returns `nil`.